# Does MFC's SDI and MDI applications automatically adjust to the user's screen resolution, unlike the dialog based application?

Tags: mfc

I created a dialog based program but it wouldn't adjust automatically to the user's screen resolution.  I was wondering if a VC++ MFC SDI or MDI would automatically adjust to the user's screen resolution without any hard coding.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no screen resolution adjustment in MFC.